# Infinitesimal Rotation under Orthogonal Similarity Transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotation, linear-algebra

I’m reading charpter 4.8 of Goldstein’s classical mechanics 3rd edition that deals with infinitesimal rotations, and the following is the part I got stuck:

> (p.166~167) If $d\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ is to be a vector in the same sense as $\mathbf{r}$, it must transform under $\mathbf{B}$ in the same way. As we shall see, $d\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ passes most of this test for a vector, although in one respect it fails to make the grade. One way of examining the transformation properties of $d\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ is to find how the matrix $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ transforms under a coordinate transformation. The transformed matrix $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}’$ is obtained by a similarity transformation:
>   \begin{equation} \boldsymbol{\epsilon}’=B\boldsymbol{\epsilon}B^{-1}\end{equation}
>   As the antisymmetry property of a matrix is preserved under an orthogonal similarity transformation, $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}’$ consists of nonvanishing elements $d\Omega’_i$ such that \begin{equation}d\Omega'_i=|B|b_{ij}d\Omega_j.\end{equation}

How can I derive the last formula about $d\Omega’_i$? Also, why does the transformation law for an axial vectors which do not change sign under inversion have to be of the form of this formula? I appreciate your help.

Comment: If dΩ is to be a vector in the same sense as r, it must transform under B in the same way. What does this part mean? I'm having trouble understanding this paragraph, I'm self studying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} 
\newcommand{\e}{\bl=}
\newcommand{\p}{\bl+}
\newcommand{\m}{\bl-}
\newcommand{\gr}{\bl>}
\newcommand{\les}{\bl<}
\newcommand{\greq}{\bl\ge}
\newcommand{\leseq}{\bl\le}
\newcommand{\plr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\blr}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\lara}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\lav}[1]{\langle#1|}
\newcommand{\vra}[1]{|#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavra}[2]{\langle#1|#2\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavvra}[3]{\langle#1|\,#2\,|#3\rangle}
\newcommand{\vp}{\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\newcommand{\hp}[1]{\hphantom{#1}} 
\newcommand{\x}{\bl\times}
\newcommand{\qqlraqq}{\qquad\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}\qquad}
\newcommand{\qqLraqq}{\qquad\boldsymbol{\e\!\e\!\e\!\e\!\Longrightarrow}\qquad}
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}
$

Let $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ the $3\times 3$ antisymmetric matrix in the textbook (equation 4.69)
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\mathrm d\Omega_3  &  \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\Omega_2 \hphantom{-}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{\frac{a}{b}}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\Omega_3  & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\mathrm d\Omega_1 \hphantom{-}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{\frac{a}{b}}}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\mathrm d\Omega_2 & \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\Omega_1 & \hphantom{-}0 \hphantom{-}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{\frac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}
For the matrix   $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ we have formally
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\boldsymbol{=} \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{\times}
\tag{02}\label{02}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\left(\mathrm d\Omega_1,\mathrm d\Omega_2,\mathrm d\Omega_3\right)
\tag{03}\label{03}
\end{equation}

Now, under a general change of the coordinate system, that is under a similarity transformation by an invertible matrix  $\mathrm S$, the antisymmetric matrix $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ in the new system is
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\epsilon'}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm S\,\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\,\mathrm S^{\boldsymbol{-}1}
\tag{04}\label{04}
\end{equation}
The new matrix $\boldsymbol{\epsilon'}$  is not antisymmetric in general. But if the similarity is produced by an **orthogonal** matrix $\mathrm B$ with the well-known properties<sup>(1)</sup>
\begin{equation}
\mathrm B^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm B^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\,,\quad \det(\mathrm B)=\vert \mathrm B \vert \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}1 \qquad (^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\text{transpose})
\tag{05}\label{05}
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\epsilon'}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm B\,\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\,\mathrm B^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm B\,\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\,\mathrm B^{\boldsymbol{\top}}
\tag{06}\label{06}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\epsilon'}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathrm B\,\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\,\mathrm B^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\right)^{\boldsymbol{\top}}=\mathrm B\,\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\,\mathrm B^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\stackrel{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\boldsymbol{=-}\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!=}}\boldsymbol{-}\mathrm B\,\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\,\mathrm B^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\boldsymbol{=-}\boldsymbol{\epsilon'}
\tag{07}\label{07}
\end{equation}
that is the matrix $\boldsymbol{\epsilon'}$ is antisymmetric and it could be represented by a vector $\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega'}$
\begin{equation}
\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega'}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\left(\mathrm d\Omega'_1,\mathrm d\Omega'_2,\mathrm d\Omega'_3\right)
\tag{08}\label{08}
\end{equation}
as follows
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\epsilon'}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\mathrm d\Omega'_3  &  \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\Omega'_2 \hphantom{-}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{\frac{a}{b}}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\Omega'_3  & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\mathrm d\Omega'_1 \hphantom{-}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{\frac{a}{b}}}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\mathrm d\Omega'_2 & \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\Omega'_1 & \hphantom{-}0 \hphantom{-}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{\frac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega'}\boldsymbol{\times}
\tag{09}\label{09}
\end{equation}

Now, we'll try to find the relation between the infinitesimal vectors $\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega},\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega'}$.

So, let a vector $\mathbf r$ in the unprimed coordinate system. In this system the vector $\mathbf r$ is transformed by the infinitesimal transformation $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ to an infinitesimal vector $\mathrm d\mathbf s$
\begin{equation}
\mathrm d\mathbf s \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\,\mathbf r \boldsymbol{=} \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf r 
\tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation}

In the primed coordinate system produced from the uprimed one via an orthogonal similarity transformation  $\mathrm B$ we'll have
\begin{equation}
\mathrm d\mathbf s' \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\epsilon'}\,\mathbf r' \boldsymbol{=} \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega'}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf r' 
\tag{11}\label{11}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathbf r'\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm B\,\mathbf r\,, \quad\boldsymbol{\epsilon'}\boldsymbol{=} \mathrm B\,\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\,\mathrm B^{\boldsymbol{-}1}
\tag{12}\label{12}
\end{equation}
But then we must have
\begin{align}
\mathrm d\mathbf s'\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm B\,\mathrm d\mathbf s \quad  &\stackrel{\eqref{10},\eqref{11}} {\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}} \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega'}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf r' \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm B\,\left(\boldsymbol{-}\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf r\right)\quad \stackrel{\eqref{12}} {\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}}
\nonumber\\
& \mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega'}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathrm B\,\mathbf r  \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm B\,\left(\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf r\right)
\tag{13}\label{13}
\end{align}

The following identity shows how the outer product of two vectors is transformed by an **orthogonal** transformation $\mathrm B$ in terms of the transforms of these two vectors
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
\mathrm B\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{=}\vert \mathrm B \vert \cdot\left(\mathrm B\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathrm B\mathbf b\right)\stackrel{\eqref{05}} {\boldsymbol{=\!=}}\boldsymbol{\pm}\left(\mathrm B\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathrm B\mathbf b\right) \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:}
\tag{14}\label{14}
\end{equation}
For a proof of the identity \eqref{14} see the **ADDENDUM A**<sup>(2)</sup>.

Using identity \eqref{14} equation \eqref{13} yields
\begin{align}
 \mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega'}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathrm B\,\mathbf r  \boldsymbol{=}&\mathrm B\left(\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf r\right) \boldsymbol{=}\vert \mathrm B \vert \cdot\bigl[\mathrm B\left(\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega}\right) \boldsymbol{\times}\mathrm B\mathbf r\bigr]\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}
\nonumber\\
& \underbrace{\bigl[\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega'}\boldsymbol{-}\vert \mathrm B \vert \cdot\mathrm B\left(\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega}\right)\bigr]}{}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathrm B\,\mathbf r  \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{0}
\tag{15}\label{15}
\end{align}
Since \eqref{15} must be valid for any $\mathbf r$, so for any  $\mathrm B\,\mathbf r$, the infinitesimal vector over the under-brace must be $\boldsymbol{0}$ that is
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega'}\boldsymbol{=}\vert \mathrm B \vert \cdot\mathrm B\left(\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega}\right)\boldsymbol{=\pm}\mathrm B\left(\mathrm d\boldsymbol{\Omega}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:}
\tag{16}\label{16}
\end{equation}
qed.

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!$

<sup>(1)
Note that an orthogonal matrix $\:\mathrm B\:$ with  $\:\vert \mathrm B \vert\boldsymbol{=+}1\:$ represents a pure rotation, while an orthogonal matrix $\:\mathrm B\:$ with  $\:\vert \mathrm B \vert\boldsymbol{=-}1\:$ represents a pure rotation plus a reflection.</sup>

---

<sup>(2)
**ADDENDUM A**</sup>

<sup>If  $\mathrm M$ is a real $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix then :   
\begin{equation}
\mathrm M^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm M^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\,,\quad \det(\mathrm M)\boldsymbol{=}\vert \mathrm M \vert \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}1 \qquad (^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\text{transpose})
\tag{A-01}\label{A-01}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
\mathrm M\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{=}\vert \mathrm M \vert\cdot \left(\mathrm M\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathrm M\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\left(\mathrm M\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathrm M\mathbf b\right)\quad \mathbf a,\mathbf b \in \mathbb R^{3} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:}
\tag{A-02}\label{A-02}
\end{equation}</sup>

---

<sup>*Proof of identity \eqref{A-02}*</sup> 


<sup>If $\:\mathrm M\:$  is an **invertible** linear transformation in $\:\mathbb{C}^{3}\:$  represented by the $\:3\times 3\:$  complex matrix  
\begin{equation}
\mathrm M\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathrm m_{11} & \mathrm m_{12} & \mathrm m_{13} \\
  \mathrm m_{21} & \mathrm m_{22} & \mathrm m_{23} \\
  \mathrm m_{31} & \mathrm m_{32} & \mathrm m_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \\
  \boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \\
  \boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-03}\label{A-03}
\end{equation}
where $\:\boldsymbol{\rho}_{i}\; (i=1,2,3) \:$ denote its row complex 3-vectors
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathrm m_{11},\mathrm m_{12},\mathrm m_{13}\right)\quad \boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathrm m_{21},\mathrm m_{22},\mathrm m_{23}\right)\quad \boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathrm m_{31},\mathrm m_{32},\mathrm m_{33}\right)
\tag{A-04}\label{A-04}
\end{equation}
 then its inverse $\:\mathrm M^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\:$ is expressed in column complex 3-vector form as follows
\begin{equation}
\mathrm M^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right)}{\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right)} & 
  \dfrac{\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\right)}{\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\right)} & 
  \dfrac{\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\right)}{\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\right)}     
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-05}\label{A-05}
\end{equation} 
and since from linear algebra for the determinant of $\:\mathrm M\:$ we have
\begin{equation} 
\det\left(\mathrm M\right) \boldsymbol{=}\vert \mathrm M \vert \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}  \boldsymbol{\cdot} \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right)\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\right) \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}  \boldsymbol{\cdot} \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\right) \boldsymbol{\neq} 0
\tag{A-06}\label{A-06}
\end{equation}   
equation \eqref{A-05} yields
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\: 
\mathrm M^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\boldsymbol{=} 
\dfrac{1}{\vert \mathrm M \vert}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right) &
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\right) & 
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\right)
\end{bmatrix}\:\:}
\tag{A-07}\label{A-07}
\end{equation}</sup>


<sup>Note that here the outer product $\:\mathbf{a}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\:$ 
of two complex 3-vectors $\:\mathbf{a}= \left(\mathrm{a}_{1},\mathrm{a}_{2},\mathrm{a}_{3}\right)\:$ and $\:\mathbf{b}= \left(\mathrm{b}_{1},\mathrm{b}_{2},\mathrm{b}_{3}\right)\:$ is defined as if they are real 3-vectors
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathrm{a}_{2}\mathrm{b}_{3} - \mathrm{a}_{3}\mathrm{b}_{2} \\
  \mathrm{a}_{3}\mathrm{b}_{1} - \mathrm{a}_{1}\mathrm{b}_{3} \\
  \mathrm{a}_{1}\mathrm{b}_{2} - \mathrm{a}_{2}\mathrm{b}_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-08}\label{A-08}
\end{equation}
while the expression $\:\mathbf{a}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{b}\:$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{b}=\mathrm{a}_{1}\mathrm{b}_{1}+\mathrm{a}_{2}\mathrm{b}_{2}+\mathrm{a}_{3}\mathrm{b}_{3}
\tag{A-09}\label{A-09}
\end{equation}
not to be confused with the usual inner product in $\:\mathbb{C}^{3}\:$
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\langle}\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\boldsymbol{\rangle}=\mathrm{a}_{1}\overline{\mathrm{b}}_{1}+\mathrm{a}_{2}\overline{\mathrm{b}}_{2}+\mathrm{a}_{3}\overline{\mathrm{b}}_{3}
\tag{A-10}\label{A-10}
\end{equation}</sup>


<sup>Now, in the special case of a real orthogonal matrix $\:\mathrm M\:$ we have $\:\mathrm M^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm M^{\boldsymbol{\top}}$, see eq.\eqref{A-01}. From eq.\eqref{A-03}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm M^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathrm m_{11} & \mathrm m_{21} & \mathrm m_{31} \\
  \mathrm m_{12} & \mathrm m_{22} & \mathrm m_{32} \\
  \mathrm m_{13} & \mathrm m_{23} & \mathrm m_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\rho}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}_{1} &
  \boldsymbol{\rho}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}_{2} &
  \boldsymbol{\rho}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}_{3} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-11}\label{A-11}
\end{equation}
Equating $\:\mathrm M^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\:$ and $\:\mathrm M^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\:$ as given by equations \eqref{A-07} and \eqref{A-11} respectively we have
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right)}{\vert \mathrm M \vert}\quad \boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\right)}{\vert \mathrm M \vert}\quad \boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\right)}{\vert \mathrm M \vert}
\tag{A-12}\label{A12}
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{equation}
\mathrm M\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right) \\
  \boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right) \\
  \boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right) 
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\dfrac{1}{\vert \mathrm M \vert}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right) \\
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right) \\
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right) 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-13}\label{A-13}
\end{equation}
Using the identity
\begin{equation}
\left(\mathbf c\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf d\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathbf c\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)\left(\mathbf d\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\mathbf c\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\left(\mathbf d\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)
\tag{A-14}\label{A-14}
\end{equation}
we have 
\begin{align}
\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right)  & \boldsymbol{=}\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)
\tag{A-15.1}\label{A-15.1}\\
\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right)  & \boldsymbol{=}\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)
\tag{A-15.2}\label{A-15.2}\\
\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right)  & \boldsymbol{=}\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)
\tag{A-15.3}\label{A-15.3}
\end{align}
and equation \eqref{A-13} yields 
\begin{align}
\mathrm M\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right) & \boldsymbol{=}
\dfrac{1}{\vert \mathrm M \vert}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right) \\
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right) \\
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1} \boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf b\right) 
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}
\dfrac{1}{\vert \mathrm M \vert}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right) \\
 \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right) \\
 \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}
\dfrac{1}{\vert \mathrm M \vert}
%\begin{pmatrix}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)\\
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)\\
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf a\right)
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathrm M\mathbf a}
\boldsymbol{\times}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\\
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{2}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)\\
  \left(\boldsymbol{\rho}_{3}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf b\right)
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathrm M\mathbf b}
\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{y}}{\dfrac{x}{y}}}
%\end{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\dfrac{1}{\vert \mathrm M \vert}\left(\mathrm M\mathbf a \boldsymbol{\times}\mathrm M\mathbf b\right)
\tag{A-16}\label{A-16} 
\end{align}
Given that $\:\vert \mathrm M \vert^2\boldsymbol{=}1$, that is $\:1/\vert \mathrm M \vert\boldsymbol{=}\vert \mathrm M \vert$, we have finally the proof of identity \eqref{A-02}.</sup>

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!$

<sup>**ADDENDUM B** 
Answer to Kashmiri's comment :</sup>


<sup>If $\:\mathrm d\bl\Omega\:$ is to be a vector in the same sense as $\:\mathbf r\:$, it must transform under $\:\mathbf B\:$ in the same way. What does this mean? – Kashmiri  Nov 14'21</sup>

---

<sup>Under a rotation $\:\mathbf B\:$ of the coordinates system for the new coordinates of a position vector $\:\mathbf r\:$ we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbf r \qqlraqq \mathbf B\,\mathbf r
\tl{B-01} 
\end{equation}</sup>
 
 
 
<sup>Now the vector $\:\mathrm d\mathbf r'\e\mathrm d\mathbf\Omega\x\mathbf r\:$ as the displacement of the position vector $\:\mathbf r\:$ under the infinitesimal rotation $\:\mathrm d\bl\Omega\:$ is also a position vector so it is transformed by coordinates similarly
\begin{equation}
 \mathrm d\mathbf r'\e\mathrm d\mathbf\Omega\x\mathbf r \qqlraqq \mathbf B\plr{\mathrm d\mathbf r'}\e\mathbf B\plr{\mathrm d\mathbf\Omega\x\mathbf r}\e\mathbf B\plr{\mathrm d\mathbf\Omega}\x\mathbf B\plr{\mathbf r}
\tl{B-02} 
\end{equation}
For the last to the right equality see \eqref{A-02} proved in **ADDENDUM A**. But then in the new coordinates system the infinitesimal rotation is represented by the infinitesimal vector $\:\mathrm d\bl\Omega'\e\mathbf B\plr{\mathrm d\mathbf\Omega} $.</sup>

 
<sup>So it's reasonable to argue that $\:\mathrm d\bl\Omega\:$ behaves as a vector like the position vector $\:\mathbf r\:$ and is transformed under rotations $\:\mathbf B\:$ as the latter does. –</sup>

Comment: If dΩ is to be a vector in the same sense as r, it must transform under B in the same way. What does this mean?

Comment: thank you. How do i Award the bounty?

Comment: yes, you took so much pains to write this so neatly. I wanted to thank you.

Answer (score 2):

How is the angular velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$ is transferred ?

Lets look at this equation:

$$\vec{v}=\vec{\omega}\times \vec{r}=\tilde{{\omega}}\,\vec{r}\tag 1$$

where

$$\tilde{{\omega}}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & -\omega_z & \omega_y \\
  \omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\
  -\omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

a antisymmetric skew matrix.

we transformed the vector $\vec{v}$ and  $\vec{r}$ with arbitrary orthogonal transformation matrix $S$ where $\det(S)\ne 0=\pm 1$

$\vec{v'}=S\,\vec{v}$ ,$\vec{r'}=S\,\vec{r}$

and get with  equation (1)

$$\vec{v'}=S\,\vec{v}=S\,\tilde{\omega}\,\vec{r}=S\,\tilde{\omega}\,S^{T}\,\vec{r'}
\overset{!}{=}\tilde{\omega'}\,\vec{r'}
\quad $$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\tilde{\omega'}=S\,\tilde{\omega}\,S^{T
}\tag 2$$

Example:

$$S=\begin{bmatrix}
   -1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$\Rightarrow$ equation (2)

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & -\omega'_z & \omega'_y \\
  \omega'_z & 0 & -\omega'_x \\
  -\omega'_y & \omega'_x & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   -1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & -\omega_z & \omega_y \\
  \omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\
  -\omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}
   -1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & \omega_z & -\omega_y \\
  -\omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\
  \omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$\vec{\omega'}=\begin{bmatrix}
   \omega_x \\
   -\omega_y \\
    -\omega_z\\
 \end{bmatrix}=-S\,\vec{\omega}=\det(S)\,S\,\vec{\omega}$$

$$\boxed{\vec{\omega'}=\det(S)\,S\,\vec{\omega}}$$

obviously is the transformation of the angular velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$ , if the determinate of the transformation matrix $S$ not equal one ,different from the transformation of a "regular" vector, this is why the angular velocity vector is a pseudovector.

Comment: $B\epsilon B^{-1}$ Goldstein book is wrong?. The result is in general not anti symmetric matrix, I correct it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I prove that the minus sign of $\vec{\omega ’}=-S\vec{\omega}$ is in fact the determinant of the transformation $S$ in general case?

Comment: Please see Goldstein book

Comment: @Frobenius a little bit confusing because in this case $B^{-1}=B^{T}$

Comment: @Frobenius I edit the dokument so I think it is now correct?. Thank for your remarks

Answer (score 0):

How is the angular velocity vector $~\mathbf{\omega}~$ is transferred ?

with

$$\mathbf \omega=\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_1 \\
  \omega_2\\
  \omega_3
\end{bmatrix}\quad ,\mathbf{\tilde{\omega}}= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{3}}&\omega_{{2}}
\\ \omega_{{3}}&0&-\omega_{{1}}\\ -\omega_{{2}}&\omega_{{1}}&0\end {array} \right]
$$

hence

$$ \mathbf{\tilde{\omega}}_{ij}=-\epsilon_{ijk}\,\mathbf\omega^k$$

where $~\epsilon_{ijk}~$ is the Levi-Civita tensor and no summation over $~ijk~$ indices.

from here you obtain that
$$\epsilon^{ijk}\,\mathbf{\tilde{\omega}}_{ij}=-\underbrace{\epsilon^{ijk}\,\epsilon_{ijk}}_{=1}\,\mathbf\omega^k\\
\mathbf\omega^k=-\epsilon^{ijk}\,\mathbf{\tilde{\omega}}_{ij}$$

for example $~k=1~$ and only $~\epsilon^{231}\ne 0=1~,~\epsilon^{321}\ne 0=-1$

$$\omega^1=-\epsilon^{231}\,\mathbf{\tilde{\omega}}_{23}=\omega_1\\
\omega^1=-\epsilon^{321}\,\mathbf{\tilde{\omega}}_{32}=\omega_1$$

now if you transformed the vector $~\mathbf\omega~$ with the transformation matrix $~\mathbf S~$  you obtain

$$\mathbf \Omega= \pm\,S\,\mathbf\omega=\det(S)\,S\,\mathbf\omega\quad \Rightarrow\\
\widetilde\Omega=\det(S)\,\mathbf{\widetilde{S\,\omega}}=\det(S)\,\mathbf S\,\tilde \omega\,\mathbf{S}^{-1}\quad\Rightarrow$$
$$\Omega^k=
-\det(S)\,\epsilon^{ijk}\,\left(\mathbf{\widetilde{S\,\omega}}\right)_{ij}\quad\quad (1)$$

you can check that equation (1) is equal to

$$\mathbf\Omega=\det(S)\,\mathbf S\,\mathbf\omega\quad\quad (2)$$

**Example**

$$\mathbf S=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} -\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}
\\  0&1&0\\  \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\,
\sqrt {2}\end {array} \right]
\quad,\det(S)=-1
$$

$$\mathbf\omega=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \omega_{{1}}\\ \omega_{{2}
}\\ \omega_{{3}}\end {array} \right]
\quad,
\mathbf{\widetilde{S\,\omega}}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}\omega_{{1}}+\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2
}\omega_{{3}}&-\omega_{{2}}\\ -\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}\omega_
{{1}}-\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}\omega_{{3}}&0&-\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}\omega_{{1}}+\frac{1}{2}\,
\sqrt {2}\omega_{{3}}\\ \omega_{{2}}&\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}
\omega_{{1}}-\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}\omega_{{3}}&0\end {array} \right]
$$

with equation (1)

$$\Omega^1=-(\det(S)\epsilon^{231}\,\left(\mathbf{\widetilde{S\,\omega}}\right)_{23}=
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\omega_1-\omega_3)$$

with equation (2)

$$\mathbf\Omega=\det(S)\,\mathbf S\,\mathbf\omega=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}\omega_{{1}}-\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}
\omega_{{3}}\\  -\omega_{{2}}\\ -1/
2\,\sqrt {2}\omega_{{1}}-\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {2}\omega_{{3}}\end {array}
 \right]
$$

notice that the transformation matrix $~\mathbf S~$ is orthogonal