# Infinitesimal rotation vector

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors, rotational-kinematics

Chapter 4.8, Goldstein 3rd ed classical mechanics  under infinitesimal rotations
(p.166~167)

($\mathbf{B}$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\mathbf{r}$ is a position vector and $d\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ is the infinitesimal rotation
"vector" which we are trying to prove is indeed a vector)

> If $d\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ is to be a vector in the same sense as $\mathbf{r}$, it must transform under $\mathbf{B}$ in the same way.

What is the author trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goldstein says that under a coordinate transformation by $\boldsymbol{B}$ we have $\boldsymbol{r'=Br}$ but **not** $d\boldsymbol{\Omega'=B\,d\Omega}\,.$ The correct transformation is
$$
\boldsymbol{d\Omega'=|B|B\,d\Omega={\rm det}(B)B\,d\Omega}\,.
$$
See his eq. (4.74) and also the [accepted answer to this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/465916/infinitesimal-rotation-under-orthogonal-similarity-transformation?rq=1).

Comment: Yes thank you very much.